# Smallest possible Label inside a Grid with line breaks

Tags: maui

I have a `Label` inside a `Grid`. I want:

- The `Grid` and the `Label` to be as small as possible.
- The `Label` should use up to two lines if necessary.

This is what I have:

```
<VerticalStackLayout Spacing="8">
    <Label Text='With HorizontalOptions="Start":' />
        
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#FCC" HorizontalOptions="Start">
        <Label
                Text="This will not wrap."
                MaxLines="2"
                />
    </Grid>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="#FCC" HorizontalOptions="Start">
        <Label
                Text="This will not wrap. This will not wrap. This will not wrap. This will not wrap. This will not wrap. This will not wrap. This will not wrap. This will not wrap. "
                MaxLines="2"
                />
    </Grid>

    <Label Text='With HorizontalOptions="Fill":' />

    <Grid BackgroundColor="#CFC" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Label
                Text="This wraps, but fills."
                MaxLines="2"
                />
    </Grid>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="#CFC" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Label
                Text="This wraps, but fills. This wraps, but fills. This wraps, but fills. This wraps, but fills. This wraps, but fills. This wraps, but fills. This wraps, but fills. This wraps, but fills. This wraps, but fills."
                MaxLines="2"
                />
    </Grid>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by: "The Grid and the Label to be as small as possible." Obviously you could set the WidthRequest to 1 but I doubt this is what you mean :). When should the Label break?

Comment: Good question :-) If it fits in one line, it should do so. If more lines are necessary, it should fill the screen and then break to next line.

Comment: So what you expected: short label in red, long label in green? Probably still a bug with label, https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10494. Could you describe the user requirement to see if any workaround?

Comment: Eg: replace your second pink ```Grid``` with ```StackLayout```. (* A bug about the label in Grid) But not sure aligns with your actual requirement.

Comment: This could be a potential issue as Shaw pointed out. If possible, you can show us all the xaml code.

Comment: @Shaw, you right, looks like a known bug. If I replace the second `Grid` with an `StackLayout` it does wrap.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT, the code above is the entire XAML. Just create a new maui app and replace the content inside the `ContentPage`.

Answer (score 1):

In conclusion, this is a known issue that be tracked in this thread:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10494. As @Shaw suggested, we can replace the `Grid` with an `StackLayout` to fix the issue. I'll keep an eye on the thread until this is being totally solved.

Thanks for your feedback and patience!